# Steps are not showing in Allure Report in Selenium Java page object model

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml, allure

I am using Page Object Model with Selenium WebDriver with Java, when I generate a report via allure serve command, All status, Epic, Stories, etc. are showing but Steps are not showing to me.
The dependencies details are given in a code
[image: Test Steps in PageObject Class]

```
    <build>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    
</project>
```

dependencies is given here which are included in pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-jsonunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Please, paste the code in inline-block instead of screenshot

Comment: added pom.xml code